# Is there any way to use ws:outbound-gateway with axis generated stubs

Tags: web-services, spring-integration, apache-axis

I'm new to spring integration framework...

I want to connect to soap endpoint with `ws:outbound-gateway`.
Is there any way to use `ws:outbound-gateway` with axis generated stubs?

I googled but couldn't get a proper example.

Answer (score 0):

The out of the box gateway uses Spring WebServices (`WebServiceTemplate`), not Axis.

However, it's easy enough to invoke the Axis stubs from your own POJO code and invoke that from an integration messaging flow using a [Service Activator](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#overview-endpoints-service-activator); more details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#service-activator) regarding configuration, options etc.